# IJCADの.NETで寸法値の色を変更する方法

Tags: .net, ijcad

寸法値の色を変更しようと以下のようにした場合には
寸法線のみの色が変更されます。
寸法値のみの色を変更する方法はないでしょうか。

Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
using(Transaction trans = doc.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
{
ObjectId ObjId;// 寸法線のObjectIDが代入されています
Dimension dim = trans.GetObject(ObjId,OpenMode.ForWrite) as Dimension;
dim.Color = GrxCAD.Colors.Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

寸法オブジェクトのDimclrtプロパティを変更することで、寸法値の色を変更することができます。